# Calling a Method Using a Nested Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I want to develop a generic pipeline. That means I call one element which then calls the next, etc. As far as it goes, it works the way it's supposed to. 
Now I want to develop an Abstract class which (in case Tinput / TOutput is a list) processes the elements via the abstract method ProcessOne. 
I'm aware that something must have to do with the generic types.
Unfortunately, C# doesn't like it. What am I doing wrong? May there also be a better way to do this (feel free to provide different approaches).

```
public interface IPipeline<out TOutput>
{
    TOutput Process();
}

public abstract class PipeItem<TInput, TOutput> : IPipeline<TOutput>
{
    protected readonly IPipeline<TInput> nextPipeItem;

    protected PipeItem(IPipeline<TInput> nextPipeItem)
    {
        this.nextPipeItem = nextPipeItem;
    }

    public abstract TOutput Process();
}

public abstract class CollectionPipe<TInput, TOutput> : PipeItem<TInput, TOutput> 
        where TInput : List<TInput>
        where TOutput : List<TOutput>
{
    protected CollectionPipe(IPipeline<TInput> nextPipeItem) : base(nextPipeItem)
    {
    }

    public override TOutput Process()
    {
        return nextPipeItem.Process().Select(ProcessOne).ToList();
    }

    protected abstract TOutput ProcessOne(TInput input);

}

public class SomeImplementation : CollectionPipe<List<string> , List<char[]>> {

    public SomeImplementation() : base(new SomeNextPipe())
    {
    }

    protected override char[] ProcessOne(string input){
        return input.ToCharArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This constraint `where TInput : List<TInput>` doesn't make a lot of sense. You are saying that `TInput` has to be a `List<TInput>`

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want to say. 
It has to be a List otherwise the principle does not work.
Each item in the list is to be processed using the ProcessOne method. (See Class `SomeImplementation`)
The problem will also be there (I guess) because the generic parameter TInput/TOutput is used there as well, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you want, but it should at least give you some directions.

Instead of saying that `TInput`/`TOutput` have to be collections of themselves, you could say that `CollectionPipe` implements a `PipieItem` of a collection of `TInput` and `TOutput`:

```
public abstract class CollectionPipe<TInput, TOutput> : PipeItem<List<TInput>, List<TOutput>>
{
    protected CollectionPipe(IPipeline<List<TInput>> nextPipeItem) : base(nextPipeItem)
    {
    }

    public override List<TOutput> Process()
    {
        return nextPipeItem.Process().Select(ProcessOne).ToList();
    }

    protected abstract TOutput ProcessOne(TInput input);

}
```

Then, the implementations can just say the type they input and output, it's already known that they are collections (since they implement `CollectionPipe` rather than just `PipeItem`:

```
public class SomeImplementation : CollectionPipe<string, char[]>
{

    public SomeImplementation() : base(/*something here*/)
    {
    }

    protected override char[] ProcessOne(string input)
    {
        return input.ToCharArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it the same way in the meantime. But another general question. If we restrict a generic type with List<Type>, can I extract the type so that I can call a method with this type? For example List<ABC> and the method DoSomething(ABC).